# How should the LUIS intent methods in version 3 bot code be written in bot framework version 4?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-framework?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) article from Microsoft Docs in order to migrate our version 3 code to version 4.

However, I am not sure how to rewrite the Luis dialog. What has to be done?

I have added the below code in onturnasync, not sure how to rewrite the AfterFAQ resume method now.

Kindly help me rewrite these existing Luis methods:

```
      //The LUIS dialog service call the back the method if the conversation is part of Greeting intent
    [LuisIntent("Greetings")]
    public async Task Greetings(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        needMoreInformation = false;
        qnaInvalidMessageCount = 0;
        var messageToForward = await activity;
        string[] supportList = { "HELP", "FEEDBACK", "SUPPORT", "ESCALATE", "AGENT" };
        string qnaAnswer;

        if (messageToForward.Text == null || supportList.Any(x => x == messageToForward.Text.ToUpper()))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please reach out to ...");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
        else if (GreetingColl.TryGetValue(messageToForward.Text.Trim().ToLower(), out qnaAnswer))
        {
            await context.PostAsync(qnaAnswer);
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Forward(new QnAGreetingsDialog(), AfterFAQDialog, messageToForward, CancellationToken.None);
        }

    }
```

modified code:

```
 public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
          ...
           var luisResults = await botServices.LuisServices[LuisKey].RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    var topScoringIntent = luisResults?.GetTopScoringIntent();
                    var topIntent = topScoringIntent.Value.intent;                        

                    // Continue the current dialog
                    var dialogResult = await dc.ContinueDialogAsync();
                    // if no one has responded,
                    if (!dc.Context.Responded)
                    {
                        // examine results from active dialog
                        switch (dialogResult.Status)
                        {
                            case DialogTurnStatus.Empty:
                                switch (topIntent)
                                {
                                    case NoneIntent:

                                    case GreetingsIntent:
                                        await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(QnAGreetingsDialog));
                                        break;

                                    case CredentialsIntent:


                                    case ContactusIntent:
                                        await LuisVar.Feedback(turnContext);
                                        break;

                                    case FeedbackIntent:
                                        await LuisVar.Feedback(turnContext);
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        // No intent identified, provide some help to the user
                                        await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync("I didn't understand what you just said to me.");
                                        break;
                                }

                                break;

                            case DialogTurnStatus.Waiting:
                                // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing.
                                break;

                            case DialogTurnStatus.Complete:
                                await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                                break;

                            default:
                                await dc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: It's all here my friend ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Skin .  I now have the basic structure ready. Please guide me a little more on rewriting - taking this simple method as example:  public async Task Feedback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
            needMoreInformation = false;
            qnaInvalidMessageCount = 0;
            var messageToForward = await activity;
            await context.PostAsync("Please reach out to.");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

Comment: Please do not post multi-line code in Stack Overflow comments. It won't get formatted so it is very difficult to read. You need to edit your question to include the code.

Comment: Sure. @KyleDelaney, I have edited my question - added two basic luis intent methods in existing V3 bot which I want to migrate to V4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your question is regarding Bot Framework core v4, PFB steps to fetch intents:

1. first you need to inject LUIS services in services with key in bot framework.
2. Fetch recognizer result object using below code

```
var luisResults = await services.LuisServices[LuisKey].RecognizeAsync(turnContext, default(CancellationToken));
```

LUIS key is key used while injection of LUIS service.

3. this is how you can fetch intents using RecognizerResult object.

```
luisResults.GetTopIntent(luisThresholdScore).intent;
```

Comment: yes @Sarang, I was able to reach this point by looking at the avaliable samples. I have edited my post and added the code form my v4 application. However, I am now struck at rewriting the resume method in v3 code

Comment: @Tanmayee - Would you like to ask a new question about your new problem?

Comment: yes, I am still at the same point though I have made required changes in my new application. Kindly help me find a replacement for Context.wait in v3 code

Comment: I have added resume method in v3 like another method which takes dialogcontext as parameter and invoked this method from begindialog. However, the control does not wait until user selects the checkbox. It ends the dialog(I am calling the resume method here since there is no context.wait). Hence, there is no response after user selects the checkbox

Comment: @Tanmayee - Did you post a new question?

Comment: @Kyle, I tried to, but my account does not allow me to post new questions.

Comment: @Tanmayee - That's very strange. Are you trying to fix your problem? Please have a look at this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251113/i-cant-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: yes @KyleDelaney, I have added the additional info in my post - the only one which had negative votes

Comment: Followed your suggestions, marked the relevant replies as answer to my posts